# Java (toUpperCase)

Tags: java

В чем ошибка? Не работает код. Программа выводит "в" а не "В"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "в";
    s.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@js_cbs](/users/17711/js_cbs), строки в java иммутабельны. Поэтому вызов `toUpperCase` (и любой другой метод класса `String`) на строке не изменяет исходную строку, а возвращает новую в качестве результата.

Comment: Поэтому или System.out.println(s.toUpperCase()); или String S = s.toUpperCase(); System.out.println(S);

Comment: Ааа, догнал. Спасибо!

Comment: Можно еще 
s = s.toUpperCase(s);